# Payara 5.194 with Ubuntu16 and Java 8 failing with UnsupportedOperationException thrown from JLine

Tags: java, ubuntu, payara

Given:

A *clean* Ubuntu 16 with these versions of java and a *clean* Payara installed:

```
jdk-8u241-linux-x64.tar.gz
payara-5.194.zip
```

When:

```
./asadmin start-domain
```

Then: Yields this output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOError: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.jline.utils.Curses.tputs(Curses.java:62)
    at org.jline.utils.Curses.tputs(Curses.java:45)
    at org.jline.keymap.KeyMap.key(KeyMap.java:243)
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.key(LineReaderImpl.java:5784)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.bindKeys(LineReaderImpl.java:5792)
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.emacs(LineReaderImpl.java:5503)
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.defaultKeyMaps(LineReaderImpl.java:5479)
    at org.jline.reader.impl.LineReaderImpl.<init>(LineReaderImpl.java:277)
    at org.jline.reader.LineReaderBuilder.build(LineReaderBuilder.java:115)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.buildLineReader(CLICommand.java:1445)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.prevalidate(CLICommand.java:941)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:325)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:294)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.jline.utils.Curses.doTputs(Curses.java:78)
    at org.jline.utils.Curses.tputs(Curses.java:60)
    ... 23 more
```

For the next few months we wont be able to upgrade Ubuntu yet:(

I think the latest version of jline is causing issues; does anyone have an idea how work around this?

Comment: Did you try disabling JLine as per this documentation? https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/payara-server/asadmin-commands/disabling-jline.html

Comment: Digging a little deeper it looks like this setting has been removed in recent versions of Payara. However, it seems to be a bug in JLine itself. See here for reference https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/496 According to this report https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-6341 it seems to be caused by the setting `TERM=linux`. Just for the sake of testing it out, could you try issuing the command `export TERM=xterm` in a shell and from there start Payara. Does this look different then?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. This did the trick: export ```TERM=xterm```. Hmm, I cant see how to mark your answer as correct...

Comment: Added it as answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you are seeing is due to a bug in the JLine library.

See here for reference: [need support securtCRT terminal types - Linux](https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/496) and [Fails with an UnsupportedOperationException by jline 3.10 and 3.11.0](https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/408)

According to another issue reported against Apache Karaf ([KARAF-6341](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-6341)) it seems to be caused by the setting `TERM=linux`.

So as a workaround you could issue the command

`export TERM=xterm`

in a shell and start Payara from that shell.

Comment: Same problem with Confluent 5.4 kafka ksql CLI and this workaround worked for it as well